# Dynamic data of pug template not getting saved, when sending template to email

Tags: node.js, pug, nodemailer

I have created an email template, using the pug engine. The template is inside the `views` folder and the name is `index.pug`.

I want to dynamically add the data to the template. The data is present in the `users` array. I used this object in the template using `for each` method. Viewing the template locally, I am able to see the dynamic content in the template.

But when the same template is sent using nodemailer, the dynamic content is not visible there.

Below is the code of `index.js` file

```
const express = require('express'); // Import the express dependency
const app = express();
const path = require('path'); // Instantiate an express app, the main work horse of this server
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

const users = [ 
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "pncde" : "PB001-3W",
        "desc":"Face Mask, White (50 pcs/box)",
        "qty":"1",
        "unitPrice":"$3.00",
        "serviceFee":"$3.00",
        "amount":"$4.00"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "pncde" : "PB001-3W",
        "desc":"Face Mask, White (50 pcs/box)",
        "qty":"1",
        "unitPrice":"$3.00",
        "serviceFee":"$3.00",
        "amount":"$4.00"
    }
]
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index',{ 'users': users });
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on port 3000'))

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const {pugEngine} = require("nodemailer-pug-engine");

const mailer = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'bhavya@gmail.com',
        pass: 'pwtiuyhjtn'
    }
});

mailer.use('compile', pugEngine({
    templateDir: __dirname + '/views',
    pretty: true
}));

mailer.sendMail({
    to: 'bhavya@gmail.com', 
    template: 'index',
    subject: "Purchase Order Template for 10 products",
    ctx: { 

    }
});
```

**Can anyone please help me resolve this issue ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the `users` to the template using `ctx` object.

```
mailer.sendMail({
    to: 'bhavya@gmail.com', 
    template: 'index',
    subject: "Purchase Order Template for 10 products",
    ctx: { 
        users // <-- same as res.render('index',{ users });
    }
});
```

By the way, this `{ users }` is shortcut for yours `{ 'users': users }` just to be clear.

Comment: thank you for such a quick response :D